# C++ Unresolved external symbol with Class templates

Tags: c++, class, templates, external

Here's a simple example of using class templates in C++. This code works.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Test {
public:
   Test();
   void print();
private:
    int i;
};

template <class T>
Test<T>::Test() {
    i=1;
    cout<<"New instance"<<endl;
}

template <class T>
void Test<T>::print() {
    cout<<"Test"<<endl;
}

int main() {
    Test<int> i;
    i.print();
    return 0;
}
```

So when I separate this code in 3 files: main.cpp, Test.h, Test.cpp:

```
//Test.h
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Test {
public:
   Test();
   void print();
private:
    int i;
};

//Test.cpp
#include "Test.h"

template <class T>
Test<T>::Test() {
    i=1;
    cout<<"New instance"<<endl;
}

template <class T>
void Test<T>::print() {
    cout<<"Test"<<endl;
}

//main.cpp
#include "Test.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    Test<int> i;
    i.print();
    return 0;
}
```

I get an errors:

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Test<int>::print(void)" (?print@?$Test@H@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Test<int>::Test<int>(void)" (??0?$Test@H@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _mai
1>C:\Programming\C++\stuff\templass\Debug\templass.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

I use Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express. So I searched a lot about unresolved external symbol but didn't find anymore for this case. So what's my mistake?

Comment: "So I searched a lot about unresolved external symbol but didn't find anymore for this case." Really? A simple google search for "template unresolved external symbol" gives you the exact solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates cannot be compiled like any other source file. Both interface and implementation should live in the header file (although some split them in `.hpp` files for interface and `.ipp` files for implementation, and then include the `.ipp` file at the end of the `.hpp` file).

How would the compiler know what classes to generate when the template class is compiled?